# I am not able to acess local tunnel

Tags: url, localhost, localtunnel

I tried to make a local tunnel for my web applicaion using this command - 'ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 nokey@localhost.run' in cmd
from localtunnel.run.

I got a URL but it when I ran it on a web browser it simply says 'page is not working'
what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

localtunnel has been unsupported/maintained by its authors due to them not being able to maintain it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).